# Beautiful Soup Selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Very new to Beautiful Soup and am stuck on getting the two values from "data" in the following code. Ideally I'd like to select value1 (500) as 'item1' and the second value (442) as 'item2'.

```
<div  id="chart-1" class="charts-highchart"  data-chart="{&quot;chart&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;pie&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:null,&quot;height&quot;:null,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;[&quot;Male&quot;,&quot;Female&quot;],&quot;data&quot;:[500,442]}],&quot;exporting&quot;pane&quot;:null}"
        style=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression `re` and use following `css` selector.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div  id="chart-1" class="charts-highchart"  data-chart="{&quot;chart&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;pie&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:null,&quot;height&quot;:null,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;[&quot;Male&quot;,&quot;Female&quot;],&quot;data&quot;:[500,442]}],&quot;exporting&quot;pane&quot;:null}"
        style=""></div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
data=soup.select_one('#chart-1[data-chart]')['data-chart']
items=re.findall("(\d+)",data)
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

**Output**:

```
500
442
```

---

If you want assign in a variable use this.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div  id="chart-1" class="charts-highchart"  data-chart="{&quot;chart&quot;:{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;pie&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:null,&quot;height&quot;:null,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;[&quot;Male&quot;,&quot;Female&quot;],&quot;data&quot;:[500,442]}],&quot;exporting&quot;pane&quot;:null}"
        style=""></div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
data=soup.select_one('#chart-1[data-chart]')['data-chart']
items=re.findall("(\d+)",data)
item1=items[0]
item2=items[-1]
print(item1,item2)
```